# How do I edit my git branch if changes have done locally

Tags: git, repository, push, pull

I have used `git pull` to get the latest and then `git push`. I even tried to push forcfully

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: The normal sequence of events would be pull, make local changes, commit changes, then push the local changes.  Can you confirm the exact sequence of events?

Comment: When you say you tried to push forcefully, what command did you run and what was the response? (The "Updates were rejected because the tip..." text makes sense for `git push`, but I don't think you would get that for a force push.)

Answer (score 0):

You need first to check your:

- `git status`
- `git branch -avv`

That will tell you which branch you are in locally, and what is (if any) your upstream branch.

From there, you can have clues as to why even a `git push --force` is not enough.
(it should be, provided you are the only one working one that repository, otherwise you would need to let other users know about that force push, for them to reset their own local repository)